# Effects on csproj file when upgrading to VS2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

We are in the process of upgrading our VS2008 to the new SP1, but noticed a change in the csproj files for something that we can't find information on. Seems that the ProductVersion in the csproj file is changed from:

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
```

to

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
```

It looks like some property signalling that the csproj file is/can be consumed by VS 2008 SP1 (perhaps for the Solution Selector to peek into) but are there other hidden side-effects of this property change that we should be looking out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more likely to be the product version that *produced* the file rather than saying what it can be consumed by. I'd be very surprised to see the build version make any tangible difference.

Answer (score 1):

The major version is all that matters to the Visual Studio Version Selector to select which version of visual studio to open (incase you have both 2005 and 2008).

I guess if you have created a project in a Visual Studio with SP1 installed then it may complain and ask you to install sp1?

I dont have any VS 2008 without SP1 to test this :)

Answer (score 0):

My coworker just got SP1 courtesy of of a ninja update from corporate IT (presumably I'll be getting it after rebooting).  My RTM copy doesn't seem to care about the newer version string in all the csproj files.